# Luhn algorithms in C

Tags: c, cs50, luhn

I am using the Luhn algorithm in C for cs50 , we don't use array yet so I thought about another method.  I think my code is fine but it doesn't output anything when I enter a credit card number it just goes back to the line and doesn't print anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    long long num, n;
    int result, sum, temp;
    
    
     printf("please enter your credit card number\n");
    scanf("%lld", &num);
    
    
    
    sum = 0;
    sum = num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
    
    num = n;
    
    while (num >10)
    {
        temp = ( num % 10) * 2;
        if (temp > 9)
        {
            temp = temp - 9;
        }
        sum = sum + temp; 
        num = num / 10; 
        temp = num%10; 
        sum = sum + temp;
        num = num / 10;
    }
        
    
    
     while ( n > 10);
     
         
         n = n/10;
         
         if (sum%10 == 0)
         
         { if (n==4)
            printf("VISA");
            else if (n==3);
            printf("AMEX");
         }
         else printf("INVALID");
     
    }
```

I am missing something,  but I don't see what it is.

Comment: You scanf into `num` and then (a few lines later) do `num = n;` when `n` hasn't been assigned a value, losing the previous value in `num`.

Comment: What do you think  `while ( n > 10);` is doing?   should be `while(...){...}`.  The `;` just results in an infinite loop if `n` is greater than `10`.

Comment: Note that "number" doesn't automatically mean "integer". If you enter and store the "number" as a string, you've got a nice handy array of the digit characters ready for you. But here, there are entered individually, converted to an integer, and then unpacked back to the original digits, phew! Similarly for house numbers, PINs, and especially phone numbers where one (or more) leading zeros are significant.